# Volley CallBack Method not giving the response?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm making a app GuessTheCelebrity. So the problem is I need celebrity names and their imageUrls outside the response method so i use callback method but its not working. First i fetch data in CelebDataService class and then in Main activity i used Matcher and Pattern to get the desired response. I use Singleton Class for adding requests to requestQueue.

Here's my code:

Volley Request Class

```
public class CelebDataService  {

Context context;
String response;
String url = "https://www.imdb.com/list/ls052283250/";

public CelebDataService(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public interface CallBack {
    void onResponse(String response);
    void onError(String error);
}

public interface MatchListAsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(List<String> list);
}

public void getResponse(CallBack callBack)
{
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println(response);
            callBack.onResponse(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            callBack.onError(error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

}

Main Activity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
int cs = 0;
TextView textView;
ImageView imageView;
ImageRequest imageRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    CelebDataService celebDataService = new CelebDataService(MainActivity.this);
    celebDataService.getResponse(new CelebDataService.CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("hello", "onResponse: " + response);
            String[] result = response.split("<div id=\"sidebar\">");
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(result[0]);
            while (m.find())
            {
                urls.add(m.group(1));
            }
            p = Pattern.compile("alt=\"(.*?)\"");
            m = p.matcher(result[0]);
            while (m.find())
            {
                names.add(m.group(1));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
            textView.setText(error);
        }
    });

    Random random = new Random();
    cs = random.nextInt(urls.size());

    imageRequest = new ImageRequest(urls.get(cs), new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP,null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            textView.setText("Error");
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(imageRequest);
}
```

}

The app got crash on start because urls arraylist is empty.

Comment: You're trying to use the urls array before its filled in.  Volley is asynchronous, the callback won't be called until it finished.  This means that any code that requires data set up in the callback needs to happen in the callback.

Comment: So what should i do?